# PHTML Uncaught TypeError: $(...).lazy is not a function

Tags: magento2, module, phtml

After installing [this module](https://github.com/magezon/Magento-2-Lazy-Load-Extension) I get an error sometimes:
Images won't load and the next error will show on console:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).lazy is not a function
With a link to this section of code in the scripts.phtml

```
require(['jquery', 'lazyLoad', 'lazyLoadPlugins'], function($) {
    window.mgzLazyload = function(config) {
        var settings = {
            bind: "event",
            delay: <?= $delay ? $delay : '-1' ?>,
            threshold: <?= $threshold ?>,
            effect: "<?= $effect ?>",
            effectTime: <?= $effectTime ?>,
            afterLoad: function(element) {
                $(element).removeClass('lazy-loading').removeClass('lazy-blur').addClass('lazy-loaded');
            }
        };
        if (config) settings = $.extend(settings, config);
        $('.lazy').lazy(settings);
    }
    window.mgzLazyload();
    $(document).on('ajaxComplete', function (event, xhr, settings) {
        window.mgzLazyload();
    });
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.owl-carousel').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
            window.mgzLazyload();
        });
    });
```

I tried to fix it on my own, but can't seem to force the module to load lazy before this section.
Here is an example:
https://jobbooz.com/hombres/indumentaria/todos-los-modelos.html?sale=1&size=168

NOTE: It's not always, most of the time it will load correctly, so you have to load it a couple of times.

Answer (score 2):

May be the issue the lazyload function gets called before initialization of jquery.

Try  `$(window).load()` method.

Comment: That broke the execution because of the $() function being outside the require(), so it would try to run automatically without waiting for  jquery. What I did was adding what its on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was following Hamendra advice but calling the function again at the end basically, not before:

```
require(['jquery', 'lazyLoad', 'lazyLoadPlugins'], function($) {
    ...
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.owl-carousel').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
            window.mgzLazyload();
        });
    });
    $(window).load(function() {
    
        window.mgzLazyload();
    });
});
```

I think this just makes it try once more before giving up.
This didn't fix the error 100%, but it go from happening 1 every 4 times to 1 in 20. That's why I don't consider it fixed.

Comment: Is it not fixed yet ?

Comment: It's working a lot better, a lot, but it will fail from time to time